# How can I show the date for all files with the same name?

Tags: shell

I have multiple files with the same name in a directory tree. How can I show the date for all these files? Bonus: sort the list by date.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have file.txt in the current directory, and it also exists in the "directory" subdirectory". You can try something like this:

```
find . -name file.txt | xargs stat -c '%.10y , %n'

2020-10-07 , ./directory/file.txt
2020-10-07 , ./file.txt
```

Replace file.txt with the name of your file.

- '%.10y' will show the first 10 symbols of %y (time of last modification).
- %n will show the file name and path.

You can also use ls and awk:

```
find . -name file.txt | xargs ls -l | awk {'print $6,7,$9'}

Oct 7 ./directory/file.txt
Oct 7 ./file.txt
```

- $6,$7 will show the date.
- $9 will show the file name.

Update: If you wish to sort, you can edit the first command like this:

```
find . -name test.txt | xargs stat -c '%.10y , %n' | sort -k1
```

- "sort -k1" will sort the output by the first column.

Will be trickier with the second command because of the formatting of the date.

Update: Things will break if there are spaces in the files/directories. Here's a way around that:

```
find . -name file.txt | while read LINE; do stat -c '%.10y , %n' "$LINE" ; done
```

Comment: Seems to work, except some of the directory names have spaces in them and stat croaks on those.

Comment: Ah, the tricky spaces. You can use the approach described here: https://askubuntu.com/a/499240. The command will become: find . -name file.txt | while read LINE; do stat -c '%.10y , %n' "$LINE" ; done